# How to use pure Vim as git mergetool?

Tags: vimdiff, git

Whenever there are some git merge conflicts we would type `git mergetool` and git would automatically launch a merge tool for us to merge the conflicts. I have been using vimdiff for a long time as my mergetool, but found it actually not efficient at all as using three-way merging won't provide more information but would occupy the precious screen space.

So I am really interested in using pure vim (not in diff mode) as my git mergetool. But I can't configure it directly since git only accepts certain difftools as git mergetool(`opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc codecompare emerge vimdiff`).

So I am wondering if there is way that I can configure pure vim as my tool to solve conflicts? Note using vim to open and edit the conflicted files directly is not desired here since you would lose a lot of conveniences provided by calling `git mergetool`, including automatic file opening and automatic git staging.

Comment: If it's "pure vim (not in diff mode)" what would your workflow look like? You could also see e.g. some [other](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/660/vimdiff-and-merge-conflicts?rq=1) [questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/git-mergetool-vimdiff-command?rq=1) for customizing.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I just merge the conflicts based on the `<<<<`, `====` and `>>>>` marks. I think those information is sufficient for us to solve the most conflicts, isn't it? Besides since we have a larger window by using the pure vim, we would have better understanding of the nearby context when solving the conflicts.

Comment: What do you mean by automatic git staging? Also, i believe all the information you need is in `git help mergetool`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble After you solved the conflicts and closed the file, git would automatically add the file you just solved to index and generate a `.orig` file. This really helps you to know the progress.

Comment: Hm. Check the help page then. I think you can configure vim as your tool and use trustStatus or something similar for the staging.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `git config option merge.tool set to unknown tool: vim
Resetting to default...

This message is displayed because 'merge.tool' is not configured.
See 'git mergetool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git mergetool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc codecompare emerge vimdiff`. This is what would happen if vim is set directly as mergetool.

Comment: Well you have to configure the tool vim. Like `[mergetool "vim"] ...` in your .gitconfig. And its `trustExitCode`. Please see the links i put above for some examples using fugitive.

Comment: you could use vimdiff and when called simple issue an `:diffoff!`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this in your `~/.gitconfig` file should do what your asking.

```
[merge] 
    tool = myvimdiff
[mergetool "myvimdiff"]
    cmd = vim "$MERGED"
```

There are lots of other options for the mergetool besides `cmd`, search for `merge.<tool>.` in `man git-config` (and obviously you can customise `cmd` how you like it. When merging 4 files are available: `$LOCAL`, `$BASE`, `$REMOTE`, and `$MERGED` (again look at the documentation for that). You can see how git sets up the default tools [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/mergetools/vimdiff) if you want more inspiration.